# Using IIS7 can I get the IP that accessed a webpage at a certain time?

Tags: iis, logging, ip-address

Using IIS7 can I get the IP that accessed a webpage at a certain time?

Such as 3:41:17 am? Not a programming question, but I need to track down whoever connected and trashed my web project. So please dont close this question.

Comment: You should have asked this on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the IIS logs to see this information. It normally is recorded (originating IP address and time as well as other data - the requested page, size of response and result code).

This of course assumes that logging is turned on.